# Convert String to Date error parsing

Tags: java, string, date, format

I have looked at many examples and can still not find an answer to match my problem. I have now been stuck for an hour and need help.

I have many strings that are formated like this:

```
Wed, 06 Nov 2013 18:14:02
```

I have created a function to convert these strings into Date:

```
private static Date toDate(String pubDateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    pubDateString = pubDateString.substring(0, 25);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(pubDateString);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return date;
}
```

What I get is a ParseException: 
`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 06 Nov 2013 18:14:02"`

Could anyone help me on my first challenge? Thanks.

edit : I tried HH, and kk

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 1):

(When I originally answered the question, the format string used `hh` - it has since been changed.)

You're using `hh` for the hours part, which is a 12-hour format - but providing a string which uses "18". You want `HH`.

Additionally, I'd suggest explicitly specifying the locale if you know that the values will always use English names.

I've verified that if you specify the locale explicitly, the code definitely works - at least under Oracle's Java 7 implementation:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                                   Locale.US);
```

If it wasn't working for you without the locale being specified (but with `HH`) that's probably why - presumably your system locale isn't English, so it was expecting different month and day names.

Comment: I forgot to change but I tried HH and kk too, thank you for such a fast answer though

Comment: @Tumata: Changing your question to make it look like I'm talking nonsense isn't terribly polite. Did you *also* try specifying the locale, as I suggested?

Comment: I did not intend to make it look like this, my apologies about it. It did work after specifying the locale, the problem came from there. Thanks